# Drawing many things in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Can we draw many things in a few code line? I want to do the job quickly but I can't.

This is the code:

```
def village_pointlist_creator(village_number, timer=0):
    global pointlist
    pointlist = []
    while (village_number + 1) != timer:
        k = random.randrange(50, 551, 100)
        p = random.randrange(50, 551, 100)
        # we should check the points here.
        pointlist.append((k, p))
        timer += 1
     return pointlist

def village_display(pointlist):
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[0][0], pointlist[0][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[1][0], pointlist[1][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[2][0], pointlist[2][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[3][0], pointlist[3][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[4][0], pointlist[4][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[5][0], pointlist[5][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[6][0], pointlist[6][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[7][0], pointlist[7][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[8][0], pointlist[8][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[9][0], pointlist[9][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[10][0], pointlist[10][1]), 25)
     pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[11][0], pointlist[11][1]), 25)
```

So, I want the second part shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `for` loop to duplicate the `pygame.draw.circle()` code, then replace the changing parameters with the `for` loop variable.

```
def village_display(pointlist):
    for i in range(12):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (pointlist[i][0], pointlist[i][1]), 25)
```

I don't know if this is what you want but it would work!